# Get Level of Tree List - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, treeview

I have a javascript function which turns a flat tree list into multi-dimensional array. I want this function to also add a tree_level property to each item.

```
    function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var out = []
    for (var i in arr) {    
            if (arr[i].headerId == parent) {
                var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].workID)

                if (children.length) {
                    arr[i].children = children
                }
                out.push(arr[i])
            }
    }
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add tree-level parameter:

```
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent, level) {
    var out = []
    for (var i in arr) {  
            if (arr[i].headerId == parent) {
                arr[i].level = level;

                var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].workID, level + 1)

                if (children.length) {
                    arr[i].children = children
                }
                out.push(arr[i])
            }
    }
    return out
}
```

Comment: It is giving the last level value to all items

Comment: just shifted the level assign statement under IF statement and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Your initial function goes through n arrays n times and mutates it's argument.

An O(n) ES6 solution that does not mutate its argument:

```
function getNestedChildren(arr, root) {
    const empty = [];
    const childrenOf = {};

    // build a dictionary containing all nodes keyed on parent
    arr.forEach((node) => {
        if (!childrenOf[node.headerId]) childrenOf[node.headerId] = [];
        childrenOf[node.headerId].push(node);
    });

    // attach children to their parents and decorate with level
    const iterateHash = (parent, level) => {
        const nodes = childrenOf[parent] || empty;
        return nodes.map((node) => {
            const children = iterateHash(node.workId, level + 1);
            // remove the first argument {} to mutate arr
            return Object.assign({}, node, { level, children });
        });
    };

    return iterateHash(root, 0);
}
```

Comment: Nice example. Curious, it's O(n)? With the recursive iterateHash calls from within a loop?

I've implemented this with two loops using a lookup table (not an original idea of course): https://codepen.io/roblevin/pen/gVRowd?editors=0010 I also wanted to also use the tree to render an indented list, as I was recently asked this in an interview but ran out of time ;)

Comment: @Rob the `forEach` iterate each object in `arr` once. Each elements are all nodes in all levels thus when building with `iterateHash` I'm iterating breadth first `arr.length` times (except if there are loops and I never terminate). O(2n), but constants don't count so that makes it O(n) time. Memory is O(log n) since max memory used is at max depth. Your code is also O(n) time and O(log n) memory.